# Exporting scraped data to CSV

Tags: php, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I am currently working on a project to scrape data from a website. I have scraped all the data I need with the following code, however I would like to know what is the easiest way to output this data into a comma-delimited CSV file. I had originally planned to move all of it into a table then export that way, but I know don't if that's the most efficient method.

```
<?php 

            $html = file_get_contents("http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Alamance-County-NC/2117_rid/36.181671,-78.943291,35.912411,-79.835243_rect/10_zm/1_fr/");         

            $DOM = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $DOM->loadHTML($html);
            $finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname = 'property-address';
            $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

            $csv_values = array();
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                $csv_values[] = $node->nodeValue;     
            }
            $handle = fopen("C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\WorkCSV\work.csv", "w");
            if (false !== $handle) {
               fputcsv($handle, $csv_values);
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: @dave I see that I should be using arrays for that command. How can I turn each of these objects into an array? Each object contains about 20 or so values. I tried $myarray = array($node), but it only creates an array based off of the last value in each object, not the entire list. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: As @dave said, double escape the backslashes in your file path, change to: `$handle = fopen("C:\\Users\\Stephen\\Documents\\WorkCSV\\work.csv", "w");`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get all of my data into an array using the code provided by Dave. Also, in fopen I was using backslashes "\" , and after switching to forward slashes "/" I was able to produce an error I can work with for exporting to CSV.

Comment: You should post your working solution in this answer and accept it (or Dave's one). It'll help people who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fputcsv` and `iterator_to_array`:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
$handle = fopen("/path/to/file.csv", "w");
if (false !== $handle) {
   fputcsv($handle, iterator_to_array($nodes));
}
```

Or like this:

```
$csv_values = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $csv_values[] = $node->nodeValue;     
}
$handle = fopen("/path/to/file.csv", "w");
if (false !== $handle) {
   fputcsv($handle, $csv_values);
}
```

On the Windows platform, be careful to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file, or use forward slashes.

```
$handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\file.csv", "r");
```

Comment: That first method returns the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in /home/u314991906/public_html/scrape.php on line 74. I'm going to try the second way now.

Comment: Ok so the second method appears to work, however no files are being created. I first tried pointing to a path on my FTP then again to my local computer. Neither worked, but neither gave me an error. There are no errors, however there is also no file. I've edited my original code to show the snippet of what I'm currently working with.